# Ionic - How to add data once a time to sqlite database table?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an `sqlite` database where i would like to add some default app settings when the user opens the application for the first time, but every time i am initializing the app, data gets added to the table.

Here is my sql file content:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings(name TEXT, value BLOB);

-- INSERT or IGNORE INTO settings(name, value) VALUES ('user_lang', 'ru');
-- INSERT or IGNORE INTO settings(name, value) VALUES ('notifications', false);
-- INSERT or IGNORE INTO settings(name, value) VALUES ('font_size', '1em');
```

This snippet where i am seeding the database with some sql queries from the file:

```
createDatabaseObject() {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
        this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'appdb.db',
        location: 'default'
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
            this.database = db;
            this.seedDatabase();
        });
    });
}

seedDatabase() {
    // Load settings
    this.http.get('assets/app_database.sql', { responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(sql => {
        this.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(this.database, sql)
        .then(_ => {
            this.loadSettings();
            this.dbReady.next(true);
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
    });
}
```

I have tried another solution with if statement inside my sql file, but it gives an error that says:

`Failed to import SQL; message=sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: near "IF": syntax error`

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM settings) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO settings (value, name)
        VALUES 
        ('user_lang','ru'),
        ('notifications', false),
        ('font_size','1em');
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN  
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM settings
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a piece of cake!! by adding **UNIQUE** to column name `OR IGNORE` operators will take effect.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    settings (
        name TEXT UNIQUE,
        value BLOB
    );

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO settings (name, value)
    VALUES 
        ('user_lang', 'ru'),
        ('notifications', false),
        ('font_size', '1em');
```